# How to make div shink to accommodate floats on window resize?

Tags: html, css

I have two floats inside a div with display:table and margin:auto. It works fine centering these two divs. However when I make window smaller, one of the floats drops down like it should, but the wrapper doesn't shrink to the new size and so floats inside become aligned to the left instead of being centered. How do you make it shrink appropriately? I mean, display:table is supposed to shrink, why does it not??

So this is what I have originally with large window size

```
+----------------+ - div {display:table, margin:auto}
|+-----+  +-----+|
||float|  |float||
|+-----+  +-----+|
+----------------+
```

After making browser window smaller, div size remains the same instead of shrinking to accommodate new float position. It looks like this

```
+--------------+
|+-----+       |
||float|       |
|+-----+       |
|+-----+       |
||float|       |
|+-----+       |
+--------------+
```

And this is how it should look

```
    +-------+
    |+-----+|
    ||float||
    |+-----+|
    |+-----+|
    ||float||
    |+-----+|
    +-------+
```

Any ideas how to make this work? Is there way to do it without media queries?

Here is a sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/WerPx/1/
It works as intended with larger window size, but if you make the result window smaller, one of the floats goes underneath, but green wrapper doesn't shrink to accommodate the new size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to make a [responsive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) layout. In your example, you just need to set `width: 100%` to the wrapper. But if the design is a title more complicated (horizontal nav, footer, sidebar...) then is a good idea use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries), something like this:

```
@media (max-width:800px), projection {
  /* The browser window width must not exceed 800px or this device
     must be projected media for these rules to apply */
 }

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 800px) 
{ 
   /* style sheet that is usable when the viewport is between 500 
      and 800 pixels wide */
}
```

Further reading:

- [Responsive Tutorials and Guidelines](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/) in Smashing Magazine
- [Adaptive layouts with media queries](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/adaptive-layouts-media-queries) (tutorial)

**EDIT:** For your code this is the solution using media queries: http://jsfiddle.net/WerPx/2/

Comment: width:100% will expand the wrapper and make floats align to the left instead of being centered, this is what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: @skyisred, I have updated my answer... +1 for the good question, would be interesting a solution without using `@media` queries

Comment: Ended up using media queries after all:)

Answer (score 0):

You could set a breakpoint using a media query that changes the width of the container to be equal to the width of the floated divs.  Set the breakpoint at the point where the float drop occurs. Code explains this better:

```
<div class="div1">
    <div>Float</div>
    <div>Float</div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
.div1 {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}

.div1 div {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
}

/* If the window size is 500px or less then apply these styles */
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .div1    {
      width: 250px;     
   }
}
```

See this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atQ3L/2/) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for responsive design layout and twitter bootstrap is the name that comes to my mind along with Media Queries and using percentage values for widths. I have set up a basic demo using twitter bootstrap where you would see page behaves differently on window resize:

```
.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.ora, .ban, .man{display:none;}
.fruit-content{width:100%;}
li{display:inline-block;width:24%;text-align:center;border-bottom:1px solid #fff;background: #C0C;}
ul.upperul{margin:0 0 0 0px;width:103%;}
.custom-row{border:1px solid green;}
.selected{background: #c0c0c0;}
@media  (max-width:480px) {
    li{display: block;width: 100%;text-align: left;}
    .custom-row{border:1px solid #000000;}
    ul.upperul{margin-left: 0px;width:100%;}

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/aT5dE/24/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.col {
    width: 100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:table-cell;

}
```